# Get parameter of form on Symfony2 controller

Tags: symfony

I've the basic form, template and controller action of Symfony2 documentation for this example.

Whenever I try to get a parameter of the form in controller action I have to use this:

```
$parameters = $request->request->all();
$name = $parameters["form"]["name"];
```

However, in documentation use this:

```
$name = $request->request->get('name');
```

But this is wrong for me, in this case $name is null and the Object request(ParameterBag) contain this:

```
object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag)#8 (1) {
  ["parameters":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    ["form"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(4) "test"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you use a `formType` to generate the form? If so what does the `getName()` function return.

Comment: I agree @Biruton. Documentation is misleading.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$formPost = $request->request->get('form');
$name = $formPost['name'];
```

Or since PHP 5.4

```
$name = $request->request->get('form')['name'];
```

On my opinion, the best way to access submitted data is firstly to bind the request to the form, and then to access values from the Form object :

```
if ('POST' === $request->getMethod())
{
    $form->bindRequest($request); //Symfony 2.0.x
    //$form->bind($request); //Symfony 2.1.x

    $name = $form->get('name')->getData();
}
```

Comment: +1 for binding (in that way you can accomplish validation also)

Comment: Your first example `$name = $request->request->get('form')['name'];` will only work in PHP 5.4. FWIW.